# Re-organizing in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, I have a simple list of items, with multiple tags (C-c C-c).  I like convert this in such a way that I can display each tag  as different header and see the items under that tag. For example, if I have tags 'company' and 'fruit' applied to the item 'apple' , then I like to see 'company' and 'fruit' as  header and see the 'apple' as item under both of them.  I have many other items and I like to combine them. So I can have all fruits under 'fruit' header etc..

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to use agenda views.

To do this, add your current file(s) to `org-agenda-files` and then use the `org-agenda` command.  The `m` option allows you to perform a tag matching search across all your agenda files.  So, for example, if you wanted to list all the headlines tagged with "company" in a list, you could do so with `C-c a m company <enter>`

Answer (score 1):

Org-mode isn't made in a way that encourages you to reorganize your .org documents this way.  Instead, you should do agenda searches that give you a dynamic view of what you want to see.  E.g., if you do an agenda search for the tags 'company' and 'fruit', the agenda buffer will show all headings that have both of those tags.

As far as having a document that consists of a list of tags, without actual headings, I don't think Org would work that way very well.  For example, take the case where you say you have three tags: 'company', 'fruit', and 'apple'.  In a normal Org document all three of those tags would apply to the heading.  They would *not* apply to each other.  So if you have a case where 'company' and 'fruit' apply to apple then 'apple would have to be the headline, like this:

```
* Apple    :company:fruit:
```

It makes no sense to have a blank headline that has just tags, since as I said the tags are intended to apply to the headline text, not to each other.  So this doesn't really make any sense:

```
:company:fruit:apple:
```

What you could do is have a document like this:

```
* apple   :fruit:company:
* fruit  :apple:company:
* company :fruit:apple:
```

And in that case the agenda searches would show what you want.  But the document has some redundancy, since same term shows up in different cases as both heading and as a tag.

Comment: Probably you misunderstood. I do not have apple as tag. I have apple as headline. I need some sort of  transformation that makes tags as headline and simply list the appropriate item under them, as output of transformation in different file.  I like to reorganize for browsing, rather than searching.

Comment: You could perform that transformation, but it's not part of Org-mode, not how Org-mode works.  Org-mode does what you want, or very close to what you want, using an agenda view.  To get it, make sure the file(s) you want are in the "agenda files" list, one easy way to edit is by using the menus: 'Org', 'File list for Agenda', 'Edit File List'.  Once you have files in agenda list use search as described by R.P. Dillon, or just click with your mouse on a tag.  Headlines with that tag will show up in agenda.

Comment: Herbert Sitz: Thank you for the answer.  I can transform via any programming language and I see what you saying about agenda. Agenda will give me view of one tag at a time. There should be a way to access the internal format of the org-mode tags which can be helpful to manipulate the org-file. Unfortunately I have failed to see so far even with XOXO export.

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for, but you can search for matches on multiple tags at the same time, using C-c a m and a search string of something like `+work+urgent` to show all headlines with work and urgent tags, or even `+work+urgent-boss` for all heads with 'work' and 'urgent' but not 'boss'.  Other than that, you could could check docs for info on 'block-agenda', which lets you create a single agenda that is the composite of multiple searches.  Again, this is not exactly what you're looking for but close. Asking at official org-mode newsgroup might yield a better answer. . .